# Android UI Layout adjustment

Tags: android-layout, android

[image: UI]

I've set up the tab and basic navigation, But having problem how to create such list view in android, with 2 or more rows and have two columns as in picture below adjusted side by side(have imageview & button below each image) & another list view below that one, which is basic and simple. I'm totally new to android ui xml, please guide me, or point me to any good learning resource about this on web.

Comment: Look up `GridLayout` for the image boxes, you will need that with some padding. For the rows underneath you will need a `ListView`. Then wrap both the `GridLayout` and `ListView` inside a `LinearLayout` set to vertical. The divider line is just a View of height 1dp or something. It fits between the two other items.

Answer (score 0):

Use dashboard in your application.Just Google it about Dashboard.You will get tutorial.This is an sample dashboard view.

[image]